# How to parse and search JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

on change of the organisation a function is called where the value selected is stored into a variable org and the value selected is compared with the whole json,and all the locations corresponding to the selected organisation is printed in drop down for locations.
here is my code

```
 var json = <?php echo $response ?>;
alert(json);
alert(json.length);
var org=document.getElementById('category_id').value;
alert(org);
for(var i=0;i<json.lenght;i++)
    {


    }
for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++)
    {
        var item = json[i];
        alert(item);   
}
}

my json is 

 [{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]
```

and my form is where i have parsed the above json and included the options for organisation in my php fprm as follows i have 2 more options for locations and buildings ,here is my form ,my question is when i select an organisation the selected value is stored in a variable ,and the varisable must search for that particaular value in the json and return the corresponding locations in the object  object containing that selected organisations into the drop down holding locations

```
<label for="orgname">Organisation Name</label>
                    <select style="width: 305px;text-align:left ;"  name="category_id" id="category_id" onchange="return orgname(this)";>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php foreach($org as $key=>$val){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
<?php
}
?>                      </select>

                    <p>
        <label name="location">Location</label>

                     <select style="width: 305px;" name="category_id1" id="category_id1">
                     <option value="">Select</option>

                     </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
        <label for="building">Building</label>

                    <select style="width: 305px" name="category_id2" id="category_id2" onchange="ajax(this);">
                    <option value="">Select</option>

                    </select>
```

Comment: whats the question ???

Comment: i have modified my question

Comment: i got a tutorial but i dont understand any thing http://techslides.com/how-to-parse-and-search-json-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function orgname($org){    
    $org=$org.value;
var jsontext = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}] ';
var newArr = JSON.parse(jsontext);
    for($i=0;$i<=newArr.length;$i++)
    {
        if(newArr[$i].name==$org)
        {
            document.write("location Name:"+newArr[$i].location[0].name+"</br>");//for location
            document.write("building Name:"+newArr[$i].location[0].building+"</br>");//for building
        }    

    }    

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank a lot ,but my requirement is not this i want tp prase upto the nth element and alert all the values by setting the their lenght in the for loop any ways thank you for giving a try

Comment: please take another look .I have changed as per your requirement